# Cannot install Languages

Tags: language-support

I try to install languages on my ubuntu 12.04. Unfortunately, it is not working, I only get info: "Software database is broken. It is impossible to install or remove any software. Please use the package manager "Synaptic" or run `sudo apt-get install -f`. in a terminal to fix this issue at first"

I did try to use this command and many other, without success. Any command that I run basically does not detect anything and I still cannot use German keyboard layout. Anyone out there that could help? Ubuntu is really overwhelming..

Comment: Open Synaptic, click the "Status" button. Does the Broken section show up? If so, what's in it?

Comment: No, no broken section - everything is fine according to Synaptic.

Comment: @Aja - please register your account - you had to add "an answer" since you lost your browser cookie and therefore had to create a new account to reply.  By registering your account you can login at anytime to edit or reply.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The keyboard layout is different from the system language (or language support).

If you want to change the keyboard layout click on Dash and write "keyboard" . You will see the keyboard layout settings. Open it and you can change the layout from there. It is not necessary to have installed the German language to add in keyboard layout the German language.

[image: keyboard-layout]